# How to pass numerical values to jQuery's .css()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, type-conversion, concatenation

I'm just starting with jQuery (and Javascript in general actually) and I feel the lack of strict typing is starting to bite me.

I need to pass values like `'123px'` or `'#123'` to jQuery's `.css()`, and it's not working if I generate the strings dynamically.

So string concatenation is done with `+`.

`'123' + 'px'` **works.**
`123 + 'px'` **does not.**
`123.toString() + 'px'` ***also does not!***

Why? passing string + number concatenations elsewhere seems to work. Is this related to jQuery?
So, how can I create a string from a numerical value and a texual suffix/prefix for `.css()`?

**Example:** http://jsbin.com/ebiro4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some CSS properties, like `width()` and `height()`, have dedicated jQuery methods that take numeric arguments and convert to `px`.

For others you should try and concatenate *strings* in order to avoid unexpected results. As an example, in your jsbin, you're trying to concatenate `'#'` and `080`, which is actually `80` with an insignificant zero so you end up with `'#80'` which isn't a valid hex color code.

Comment: Thanks, thanks! `width` and `height` are what I was looking for. Plus I forgot about `080` being `80` in the example. Just waiting the timeout to accept. By the way, I still don't understand the limitation to use width and height with concatenated values (since they work otherwise). Weird.

Answer (score 3):

`'123' + 'px'` **works**

`123 + 'px'` **should also work, but do it like =>** `'' + 123 + 'px'`

`123.toString() + 'px'` **should be =>** `123..toString() + 'px'`

The last one is a little bit tricky. ECMA-/Javascripts expects full qualified decimal places in this spot. `123.0.toString()` is pretty much the same as the `..` shortcut.

`#80` is never a numeric value in Javascript.

`'#' + 080` does not work because `080` is an octal value. Firebug throws: `08 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant`.

Comment: +1 because I'd never guess `123..toString()`. But the second one doesn't work **with jQuery**. I've also tried `''.concat(123,'px')` and nothing. Look in the example, `'#' + 080` doesn't work where `'#' + '080'` does.

Comment: @CamiloMarting: it's because the preceding zero. It's an octal value. Firebug throws this: `08 is not a legal ECMA-262 octal constant`

Comment: @Camilo - I'm just wondering if on what situation will you get `080`. If it's a number then it should have been `80`.

Comment: & @Riegel: Dumb me... 180 works. Should have guessed. Used that in the example but real-world problem was with width and height and solved as per BoltClock's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use `123..toString()` since Javascript is interpreting `123.toString()` as a float value. The first thing you need to do is create a float with `123.` which is equal to `123.0` and then convert it to a string.